# How to convert the below curl command in Java using HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, json, curl, https

How to convert the below curl command to Java using HttpURLConnection?

```
curl -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic ZnJlZDpmcmVk" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://example.com:8081/rest/api/2/issue/QA-31"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. How to set headers:

   ```
       HttpURLConnection myCon = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://example.com:8081/rest/api/2/issue/QA-31").openConnection();

   myCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
   myCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
   myCon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic ZnJlZDpmcmVk");
   ```
2. After that you can read URL content in two ways

   a. you can get InputStream from Connection as

   ```
   InputStream inStream = myCon.getInputStream();
   ```

and read it as you want directly or with some reader etc.

b. by getting Content as

```
Object content = myCon.getContent();
```

For details read Java Docs for those methods it is very well documented.

BTW: keep in mind you have an SSL connection then you have to have remote server certificate in your java Key Store.